# POST ManytoMany relationship in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a ManytoMany relationship with Book model and Genres the below code works fine when i try to get data but when tried to post similar as the output but i keep getting this error

```
The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `pages.serializes.BookSerial`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
```

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description  =  models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    alternative_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    blacklist =  models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Genres(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    book = models.ManyToManyField(Book,related_name="bookgenres")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serialazer.py

```
class GenreSerial(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model =  Genres
        fields  = ['name']


class BookSerial(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    genre =  GenreSerial(source="bookgenres",many=True)


    class Meta:
        model =  Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class AllSerialed(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.filter(blacklist=False).order_by("-date")
    serializer_class = BookSerial
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to extend the BookSerial and define a create method. And in create method first you save the book object as

```
bookobject= books.objects.create(passData),
```

then create the Genres as

```
Genreobject = Genres.objects.creae(data)
```

(this data should not contain book value), and then do something like -

```
Genreobject.book.add(bookobject)
```

Comment: Not writing the complete code :) :)